# image links break in carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

https://codepen.io/fjenpen/pen/pROPov

On page load when you scroll left through the `#flexiselDemo3` each list item will not click to display it's corresponding content.

Similarly if you scroll right through all `.li`'s and come back around to the beginning each list item will not click to display it's corresponding .content.

How do I connect each `.li` with it's corresponding content no matter which way you scroll and how many times you scroll through the carousel?

```
$('#flexiselDemo3 a').click(function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".main .content").not(target).hide();
    $(target).show();
    return (false);
});

$(".main .content").hide();

var initialTarget = "#Section1";

if (location.hash.length > 0) {
    initialTarget = location.hash;
}
$(initialTarget).show();
```